# Audits of suggested edits don't show as suggested edits in the questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was reviewing and I had an [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14874355). As I was suspicious that the edition of the content might be from the comments I looked at the post. There I observed that the `(1)` following the `Edit` text didn't appear:

Audit:

> Share Edit Flag

While in previous suggested edits it did:

> Share Edit(1) Flag

This provides an easy way to identify those audits. Shouldn't an audit appear with a (1) next to Edit ?

Comment: The idea of audits is to catch robo reviewers that don't pay any attention at all. You paid attention and therefore identified the audit. Everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good spotting!

Well, the fact that you were suspicous and went to look, already shows that you were paying attention. So the audit served its purpose.
There's not really a need to pretend, on the site itself, that the post is being edited when it isn't. That would probably involve adding a lot of code - just to catch someone who is already taking extra steps before judging an edit.

For edits, it usually isn't necessary to visit the original post; most edits can be judged from the queue. But good for you that you double-checked before judging.

Quite frankly, the audits in the Suggested Edits queue are so easy, the *only* excuse to fail them is a mis-click.